# How to show a drop down list after getting list items in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to show a drop-down list after data getting the list from database. I'm getting the list data from a JavaScript file and I've to show those list items in a drop-down list. When the page loads for the first time, the drop down stays empty. But when I get list data from database, and populate the angular variable for drop-down list, it gets updated in angular, but in DOM, nothing changes. Drop-down stays empty.

This is what I did so far:
In JavaScript where I'm getting the list from database.

```
$.get("/ws/getList", dt, function (data) {
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'));
    var injector = elem.injector();
    var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
    $rootScope.$broadcast("listEvent", data);
});
```

In Angular controller where I'm trying to populate the `$scope` variable for list:

```
$scope.listForDD = [];
$rootScope.$on("listEvent", function (event,pList) {

  $scope.listForDD = pList;
  console.log($scope.listForDD);

});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">

<span style="margin-top: 6px;">Select student: </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select class="form-control" id="listDropDown" style="width: 157px;">
    <option ng-repeat="l in listForDD" value="{{l.studentName}}">
      {{l.studentName}}
    </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here's a sample list data:

```
[{ studentName: "Jane",age: 25}, { studentName: "John",age:18 }]
```

I'm getting the data in `scope` variable but drop-down list is not getting updated in HTML.

Comment: Any reason for not using in-built `$http` service?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I don't know about it. I'm new. If there's any way, kindly explain. anything will help

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the best way to fetch data from a server with the AngularJS framework is to use the framework's builtin $http service. Under-the-hood, both jQuery and AngularJS use the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

```
var url = "/ws/getList";
var config = {params: dt};
$http.get(url, config)
.then(function(response) {
   $scope.listForDD = response.data;
   console.log($scope.listForDD);  
}).catch(function(response) {
   console.log("ERROR", response);
});
```

The $http service provides a promise-based API that is integrated with the AngularJS framework's execution context and its digest cycle. It has builtin hooks that facilitate unit testing.

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overview)
- [AngularJS Tutorial - XHR & Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Comment: Actually I'm not facing any issue with fetching data. I can not include the data fetching part in angular. It's designed that way. I've to get the data from a javascript file and then send it to an agular controller. I'm getting the JSON data in angular controller too. But in html, it's not getting updated

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<span style="margin-top: 6px;">Select student: </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select class="form-control" id="listDropDown" style="width: 157px;">
    <option ng-repeat="l in listForDD" value="{{l.studentName}}">
      {{l.studentName}}
    </option>
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.listForDD = [{ studentName: "Jane",age: 25}, { studentName: "John",age:18 }];

     $rootScope.$on("listEvent", function (event,pList) {
        $scope.listForDD = pList;
        console.log($scope.listForDD);

    });
    $rootScope.$broadcast("listEvent", [{ studentName: "Jaaane",age: 65}]);

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this before and it worked perfectly. but I need the ```$scope.listForDD``` to be updated after I get the data.

Comment: The issue is, my ng-repeat value is updating in angular but in DOM it doesn't change. I tried your way and it works if I load the scope variable before loading the DOM. But i want it to be updated after the DOM is loaded

Comment: it's already in the code. The DOM gets loaded, then I call a webService "getList" to get drop down menu list from database. Then I broadcast it from javaScript and populate angular variable "listForDD" inside "$rootScope.$on" function. But the updated values are not showing in html

Comment: I have updated the code. it works fine after update the list also.

Comment: does it work in DOM too? cause I think that's what I did too if you look at my code. or maybe I'm missing something. Can you kindly show me the diffrence, that would be helpful cause for me, nothing gets updated in DOM :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209595/discussion-between-krishna-and-araf).